# How to change PDF metadata using vb.net without creating new file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, pdf, metadata

I tried all the possible components in vb.net but most of them where creating a new file for saving ..

is there a way to make the changes in the same file (just like Adobe Bridge) 
to save the time of saving ... etc

Thank you for your help ...

Comment: can you provide your code here?

Comment: i didn't create my code yet just search for such a thing .. ThAnX

Comment: Nice @eng-ali-alghabban

Comment: btw what code are you talkin about , i'll create the function after i find the right component

Comment: So effectively you are asking for a software recommendation. These are off topic on stack overflow.

Comment: How about a library of SDK ?!